# Dynamic image preview on JSP

Tags: java, image, jsp, dynamic, preview

I have a textfield inside my rich:dataTable in one column:

```
<h:inputText id="logourl" value="#{item.logoUrl}" />
```

And I have this tag in another column:

```
<h:graphicImage id="logoimage" value="#{item.logoUrl}" url="#{item.logoUrl}" />
```

One element puts the value into bean "item" and another reads it but it happens only on page rerender. What I want is when I change a value in  the image must refresh automatically.
I heard it can be done with a4j:mediaOutput butt all I found is how to create images manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to submit the form to have it change automatically, personally I would use JavaScript to do this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function swapImage(divId) {
    document.getElementById("img").src=divId;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry that's not the best example but I'm currently at work :( lol